# Is it possible to get a tree of work items in a test plan without parent/child links?

Tags: testing, tfs

Im working with a project in TFS (2017) where a test plan has been made along with suites and cases that have no relationship between them (that is, no links or parent/child relationship). In other words, they are all top level according to any queries I run. I was wondering if there was any other relationship without having to link all of these work items that could be used to query the test plan and return a tree of work items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to get the tree of work items (Test Plan/Test suite/Test case) **with a query**.

However, you can export the specific test plan with the corresponding options selected based on your requirements.

Right click the specific test plan --> Export --> Select the options

[image]